# List all validation rules for a certain model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I think I have duplication in validation of an attribute since I am getting the same validation error twice on email field.

I suspect the some gems may enforce the same validations.

Is there a way to list (in console) the validations on a certain model/ attribute and to see where they are listed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a list of validators on an attribute with

```
Model.validators_on(:attribute)
```

or even the entire list of validators for a model with:

```
Model.validators
```